# Manual annotate a ggplot with different labels, in different facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

JD Long helped me with this: [question about manual annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409357/how-to-nicely-annotate-a-ggplot2-manual).

But is it possible to do something similar on a facetted plot, such that the label style corresponds to the linestyle (aestetics) and in a way that I can annotate different facets individually?

Some data:

```
funny <- structure(list(Institution = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Q-branch", 
"Some-Ville", "Spectre"), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(5L, 
6L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Korte videregående uddannelser", 
"Mammas beer", "Mellemlange videregående uddannelser", "Tastes good", 
"Unknown", "Your"), class = "factor"), År = c(2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L), Mndr = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L), Data = c(159L, 
NA, NA, 23L, 204L, NA, NA, 12L, 256L, NA, NA, 24L, 166L, 6L, 
NA, 43L, 228L, NA, NA, 20L, 196L, 11L, NA, 37L, 99L, 14L, 9L, 
96L, 147L, 7L, 5L, 91L, 100L, 10L, 7L, 126L, 60L, 17L, 6L, 106L, 
78L, 18L, 13L, 140L, 48L, 23L, 5L, 136L)), .Names = c("Institution", 
"Type", "År", "Mndr", "Data"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
```

And a facetted plot:

```
ggplot(funny, aes(Mndr, y=Data, group=Type, col=Type)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(.~Institution)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Shane: I don't think this is a duplicate - Andreas does not want to use the data in the plot to calculate the value, but rather format his labels to match the style of the lines.

Comment: @Shane Thank you for the attention. Aniko's answer is exactly what I was hoping for. So I guess there is no need to futher clarify? Unless for posterity of cause. Thanks again.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050610/creating-a-facet-wrap-plot-with-ggplot2-with-different-annotations-in-each-plot

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The idea is that for each manual annotation you have to define not only the label, but all the variables that define the panel, color, etc. The following code adds two labels in different panels.

```
pl <- ggplot(funny, aes(Mndr, y=Data, group=Type, col=Type))+geom_line()
      +facet_grid(.~Institution)   #your plot
nd <- data.frame(Institution=c("Q-branch","Some-Ville"),  #panel
                 Type=c("Unknown", "Tastes good"),        #color
                 Mndr=c(7,12),                            #x-coordinate of label
                 Data= c(170,50),                         #y-coordinate of label
                 Text=c("Label 1", "Label 2"))            #label text
# add labels to plot:
pl <- pl + geom_text(aes(label=Text), data=nd, hjust=0, legend=FALSE)
pl
```

The `legend=FALSE` option will ensure that the small a's denoting the text are not added to the legend. You don't have to have a data frame for the labels, you could have a separate `geom_text` for each, but I find this way simpler.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the manual, the new ggplot syntax has changed a little, legend=FALSE is now show_guide = FALSE, I think.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the plots from code in the question as well as code in the answer, but both plots are identical.  No text is written on the plots in the latter case.  Has something changed in my version of ggplot2 (2.1.0)?