# Manually annotate one panel w/ multiple labels

Tags: r, annotations, ggplot2

This is very similar to this question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417623/manual-annotate-a-ggplot-with-different-labels-in-different-facets)), but I'm not quite sure how to manipulate it for my needs.

I have a faceted plot with two panels, and I would like to label three quadrants in the first panel and only the first panel.

Here is a mock data set:

```
dfr=data.frame(
 variable=rep(c("A","B"),each=2),
 x=c(2,-3,4,-5),
 y=c(-2,4,-2,6))
```

And here is the plot:

```
p=ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
 geom_point()+
 facet_grid(variable~.)+
 scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-6,6))+
 scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-6,6))+
 geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
 geom_vline(xintercept=0)
```

This is what I would like to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always create a separate data frame with the desired labels and plot them using `geom_text`:

```
dfLab <- data.frame(variable = rep("A",3),
                    x = c(3,3,-3),
                    y = c(3,-3,-3),
                    lab = c('I','IV','III'))


ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
 geom_point()+
 facet_grid(variable~.)+
 scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-6,6))+
 scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-6,6))+
 geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
 geom_vline(xintercept=0) + 
 geom_text(data = dfLab,aes(x=x,y=y,label=lab))
```

[image]

Comment: D'oh, it was an error in my code, I feel stupid now.  Thanks for answering all the same!